# Nested looping a Python list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have a list of length 6 with L[5] = 3 fixed. I need to loop it around 243 times( or something) to get the combination in a particular order.

The L[4] will keep going 1,2,3 and L[3] would be the same for that time and then it moves right to left. I know it will be some nested loop but can't do it properly. The list can be initialized as anything but L[5] needs to be 3 and the first combination will be L = [1,1,1,1,1,3] and the last combination will be [3,3,3,3,3,3] [image: The yellow highlights are the indexes and red will always be 3]

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

vals = [[1, 2, 3]] * 5 + [[3]]

for c in product(*vals):
    print(c)
```

Prints:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3)

...

(3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3)
(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3)
(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
list = []

for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        for k in range(1,4):
            for l in range(1,4):
                for m in range(3,4):
                    list.append([i,j,k,l,m])

for elem in list:
    print(elem)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 1, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I added one more nest to it but got the concept.